# Custom validation in Laravel 4

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

To add a new validation to Laravel I have done this:

made a new file called `customValidation.php` in `app/start/`

and then included it in `app/start/global.php` and tested it with an `echo()` and it worked. So it is loaded into the application now.

Then I wrote the following code to validate checkboxes in Laravel:

```
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
class customValidate extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator
{
    public function validateCheckbox($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        //if(isset($value)) { return true; } else { return true; }
        echo "this is the: " . $value;
    }
}

/**
 * Resolvers for Custom Validations
 */
Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $message){
 return new customValidate($translator, $data, $rules, $message);   
});
```

However, in my validation rules, I define :

```
`array('sex'=>'checkbox')`
```

But it does not work. Nothing happens. No error is thrown. The application behaves as if it has not executed the function at all. Also when I echo something from within the function,nothing get echoed, another evidence for the function not being called at all.

Comment: Try to `dd('stop')` inside of `validateCheckbox`, to debug and see if method gets called. From what I see, it should be registered and work.

Comment: no it does not get called

Comment: Great, now we know it does no gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When submitting the form, the radios were not set in their initial states, and this made Laravel not to look for the validator of the item. So, it doesn't have any workaround for that. What I did was I simply added an initial state to the radios and they worked.

Much Like said by Andreyco

Comment: Yeah, I always add "empty" value for radios and checkboxes using `Form::hidden('checkbox-name', false)`

Answer (score 5):

I would create custom `app/validators` folder for this then.

**1,** Create `app/validators/CustomValidate.php`

```
<?php

class CustomValidate extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator
{

    public function validateCheckbox($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        echo "this is the: " . $value;
    }

}
```

**2,** run `php artisan optimize` or `composer dumpautoload`

**3,** Somewhere register your custom validator. Perhaps add `app/validators.php` into `start/global.php`

```
Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $message){
    return new CustomValidate($translator, $data, $rules, $message);
});
```

**4,** Validate

```
$rules = ['agreed' => 'checkbox'];
$data = ['agreed' => 0];

$v = Validator::make($data, $rules);

dd($v->passes());
```

Comment: What would cause me to get `CustomValidator::setPresenceVerifier` undefined method error?

Comment: I don't understand when the CustomValidate (or the validateCheckbox function) called. Could you give explanation?