# Laravel throw Error from Model if the Condition Fails

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am doing all the validations in Model

My Rule is

```
public static $rules = array(
        'VehicleNumber' => 'required|unique:vehicle', 
        'NumberSeats' => 'required', 
        'VehicleType' => 'required', 
        'MaximumAllowed' => 'numeric|max:3',
        'VehicleCode' => 'required|unique:vehicle');
}
```

But for changing the file name and checking its size i am handling in a `SetFooAttribute`

```
public function setInsurancePhotoAttribute($InsurancePhoto)
{
    if($InsurancePhoto && Input::file('InsurancePhoto')->getSize() < '1000')
    {
    $this->attributes['InsurancePhoto'] = Input::get('VehicleCode') . '-InsurancePhoto.' . Input::file('InsurancePhoto')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Input::file('InsurancePhoto')->move('assets/uploads/vehicle/', Input::get('VehicleCode') . '-InsurancePhoto.' . Input::file('InsurancePhoto')->getClientOriginalExtension());
    }
}
```

There in the Condition

```
if($InsurancePhoto && Input::file('InsurancePhoto')->getSize() < '1000')
```

If it fails the Storing of Image, Setting Attribute won't be done.

**But How can i throw the Error to the User in this  Case ?**

Answer (score 1):

You can throw Exception with error message.

**Model**

```
if($InsurancePhoto && Input::file('InsurancePhoto')->getSize() < '1000') {
    // process image
} else {
    throw new \Exception('Error message');
}
```

In controller (where you call validation) you can catch this exception and print it to user.

Comment: Is tried, for validation, But i am not getting it any exception error message

Answer (score 0):

getSize() return integer so you should not use string for comparison as you have written 1000 in single quotes. You can create your own  custom Validation in laravel. Check this links [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375946/custom-validation-in-laravel-4) and http://culttt.com/2014/01/20/extending-laravel-4-validator/

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
return abort(500, 'Somthing went wrong');
```