# How to do Uploaded File Validations in Model in Laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

This is my Previous [Question's Continuation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27645655/4047397)

I am using Model for Validations

I will send the values to the model by this way

```
$VehicleData = Input::all();
$validation  = Validator::make($VehicleData, VehicleModel::$rules);
```

And Validate using the following rule

```
public static $rules = array(
        'VehicleNumber' => 'required|unique:vehicle', 
        'NumberSeats' => 'required', 
);
```

But Now i want to do validate the Upload File to for size and extension

I tried to do it in the Model in the `SetFooAttribute`

```
public function setInsurancePhotoAttribute($InsurancePhoto)
{
    if($InsurancePhoto && Input::file('InsurancePhoto')->getSize() < '1000')
    {
    $this->attributes['InsurancePhoto'] = Input::get('VehicleCode') . '-InsurancePhoto.' . Input::file('InsurancePhoto')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Input::file('InsurancePhoto')->move('assets/uploads/vehicle/', Input::get('VehicleCode') . '-InsurancePhoto.' . Input::file('InsurancePhoto')->getClientOriginalExtension());
    }
}
```

But I realize it is a Bad Practice. Because it will called only after the validations and when this is called `VehicleModel::create($VehicleData);`

I don't know where to do the File Validations and How in the Model.

Kindly suggest me the way to proceed.

Comment: if i understand u right ,u want to have a validation for the file upload ,like maxsize ,mime-type ,etc.. ,if so its already stated on laravel docs http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-size.

Comment: Yes i do know that and it was in the code that i pasted above, i need to know how i can have this in the Model

Comment: in the $rules array those are (input_name=>the rules) so `'InsurancePhoto'=>'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,gif|max:2000'` use (max instead of size) and now after the (validate->passes) u can do the rest like any thing else.

Comment: The thing is that i am doing all these only after validation was done. And i don't know how to make it as a rule

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the model

```
public static $rules = array(
    'VehicleNumber'  => 'required|unique:vehicle', 
    'NumberSeats'    => 'required',
    'InsurancePhoto' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,gif|max:2000'
);
```

in the controller

```
$VehicleData = Input::all();
$validation  = Validator::make($VehicleData, VehicleModel::$rules);
    if($validation->passes())
    {
        // Input::file('InsurancePhoto') stuff
        // store the data to the db
    }
```

Comment: Woww !! I didn't read about the mimes in validation,.. 2000 is kb right ?

Comment: in kb yes ,u can set it to be = to the max_file_size in the php settings.

Comment: That's great. I should have read the documentation fully . Thanks mate !