# Laravel How to Make Custom Validator?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I need to make my own validator that extends `Illuminate\Validation\Validator`

I have read an example given in an answer here: [Custom validation in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375946/custom-validation-in-laravel-4#answer-21376700)

But the problem is it doesn't clearly show how to use the custom validator. It doesn't call the custom validator explicitly. Could you give me an example how to call the custom validator.

Comment: Here's an example of a custom validation rule for checking [composite unique columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26683762/how-to-add-combined-unique-fields-validator-rule-in-laravel-4/26684043#26684043).

Answer (score 18):

After Laravel 5.5 you can create you own Custom Validation Rule object.

In order to create the new rule, just run the artisan command:

```
php artisan make:rule GreaterThanTen
```

laravel will place the new rule class in the `app/Rules` directory

An example of a custom object validation rule might look something like:

```php
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class GreaterThanTen implements Rule
{
    // Should return true or false depending on whether the attribute value is valid or not.
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return $value > 10;
    }

    // This method should return the validation error message that should be used when validation fails
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute must be greater than 10.';
    }
}
```

With the custom rule defined, you might use it in your controller validation like so:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'age' => ['required', new GreaterThanTen],
    ]);
}
```

This way is much better than the old way of create `Closures` on the `AppServiceProvider` Class

Comment: i know this is a fairly old answer, but i'm new in Laravel and could use clarification: Most examples i see with CVs show the basic usage in the Controller action. If i'm using Form Requests, would the above example work in the `rules()` function as `return ['age' => 'greaterthanten'];`?

Comment: @cautionbug, yes, you can use the CV inside of Form Request classes, you just have to import the new custom validation rules class with : `use App\Rules\GreaterThanTen`;

Comment: ['required', new GreaterThanTen] is not working, use instead [$request, new GreaterThanTen]

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if this is what you want but to set customs rules you must first you need to extend the custom rule.

```
Validator::extend('custom_rule_name',function($attribute, $value, $parameters){
     //code that would validate
     //attribute its the field under validation
     //values its the value of the field
     //parameters its the value that it will validate againts 
});
```

Then add the rule to your validation rules

```
$rules = array(
     'field_1'  => 'custom_rule_name:parameter'
);
```

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore with laravel 9. I do not know when this feature was removed.

Comment: This still works in laravel 9. I upgraded from laravel 5 to 9.x and it worked without any issue.