# How to create a custom error message for a custom validation rule in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have a request class that includes a custom rule. I can't work out how to define a custom message if that rule fails. Below is a simplified version of what I have so far, I would like to add to the array returned by the`messages()` method.

I have already defined the message in the `CustomRule` class but I would like to overide this in my `CustomRequest` class.

I tried adding `'input.CustomRule' => 'Custom error message'`, but this didn't work.

Using Laravel 5.7.

Cheers for any help!

```
class CustomRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'input' => [
                'required',
                new CustomRule
            ]
        ]
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'input.required' => 'We need to know this!'
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: possibly duplicate with this question: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265166/laravel-how-to-make-custom-validator)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel How to Make Custom Validator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265166/laravel-how-to-make-custom-validator)

Comment: I'm after slightly different info, I would like to overide the error message in my `CustomRequest` class.

Answer (score 0):

From your CustomRule return custome message.
put below code in your CustomRule.php file.

```
public function message()
{
   return 'This is custome message.';
}
```